# Using databinder syntax inside a TD on aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, html-table, databinder

I'm thinking this should be possible or something like it:

```
<td <%# "style=" DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustName") == "T" ? "border:none" : "border:solid"%>>
```

But it's not doing it for me.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this

```
<td <%# string.Format("style={0}, Eval("CustName") == "T" ? 
    "border:none":"border:solid")%> >
```

or Create a public method on the cs file like this

```
protected string GetStyle()
{
   var dt = SomeMethod();
   If (string.compare("T",dt.rows[idx][idx].Tostring(),false)==0)
    return "border:none";
   return "border:solid";
}
```

user:

```
 <td <%# string.Format("style={0}, GetStyle())%> >
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that, but you can try this instead:

```
<td style='<%# Eval("CustName") == "T" ? "border:none" : "border:solid"%>'>

</td>
```